# When should I use the numpy.genfromtxt instead of pandas.read_csv to read a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I was recently doing an image extraction part from a .csv file,the file contained a column named **pixels** with 48x48 values given as strings, so normally seeing a .csv file I used **pandas.read_csv** to try to convert pixels column to later on images, converting to **PIL images.**

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('fer2013.csv') # fer2013 competition dataset.
data.head()

        emotion pixels  Usage
    0   0   70 80 82 72 58 58 60 63 54 58 60 48 89 115 121...   Training
    1   0   151 150 147 155 148 133 111 140 170 174 182 15...   Training
    2   2   231 212 156 164 174 138 161 173 182 200 106 38...   Training
    3   4   24 32 36 30 32 23 19 20 30 41 21 22 32 34 21 1...   Training
    4   6   4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 15 23 28 48 50 58 84...
```

But, I saw another guy use numpy.genfromtxt to load the csv file from the discussions:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('fer2013.csv',delimiter=',',dtype=None)
```

But, I don't understand what's the use of numpy.genfromtxt, I saw the examples on the scipy numpy.genfromtxt docs too,

> I found the **dtype naming methods to be great**, but those are available
>   in pd.read_csv too!

:
[np.genfromtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

Would be great if someone could explain the need and use for **numpy.genfromtxt** load method, and where it would benefit on top of other methods for reading a file.

You can find the data here:
[fer2013 competition Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/challenges-in-representation-learning-facial-expression-recognition-challenge/data)

Comment: What if you don't have or want to use `pandas`?

Comment: If you're trying to get an image that is a 2- or 3D array of homogeneous type, numpy is probably the more efficient tool.

Comment: @hpaulj: Why would someone not have pandas or wouldn't want to use it? You can't do everything with numpy, can you?

Comment: @MadPhysicist : At the moment it is heterogeneous with object dtype( pixels & type) with int64 dtype (for emotions), but latter on they will be converted to **numpy arrays**, emotions will be converted to numpy array using .values if using pandas and pixels will also be converted to numpy.ndarray using **.reshape**. Could you explain your remark about the efficiency of numpy arrays, still.

Comment: This question borders on opinion.  It the pandas function works for you and is fast enough, use it.  Don't argue with those who prefer not add a pandas layer to their code.

Comment: @aspiring1 well, you can. Often, `numpy` is all you want/need. Less dependencies on projects is a good thing. The point is, `numpy` and `pandas` are two different libraries with their own utility functions. `numpy` is designed to work alone.

Comment: @hpaulj : What I meant was is there a reason to use numpy.genfromtxt in some cases, where it would be of better use, then I can add it to my list of load functions, or should I  just view it as an alternative to pandas.read_csv?

Comment: @aspiring1. One produces numpy arrays and one produces pandas dataframes. Use the one that gives you the result you want.

Comment: To get more meaningful answers you need to provide a sample file, and a more complete description of how you process the dataframe or array.  I can't download your link because it's too big and requires some sort of registration.  The description sounds like it could pose problems for both `numpy` and `pandas`.  The 2nd column is a space delimited quoted string.

Comment: When you load it with `pandas`, what's the nature of the `pixels` column?  Judging from other questions I suspect it is `object` dtype with a string for each cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it , the pandas reader is a optimized program written in C and is faster in much situation. `genfromtext` is an old python fonction with less inferring skills, that you can forget if you have pandas.

```
In [45]: df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10**6).reshape(1000,1000))

In [46]: df.to_csv("data.csv")

In [47]: %time v=np.genfromtxt("data.csv",delimiter=',',dtype=int,skip_header=1)
Wall time: 5.62 s

In [48]: %time u=pd.read_csv("data.csv",engine='python')
Wall time: 3.97 s

In [49]: %time u=pd.read_csv("data.csv")
Wall time: 781 ms
```

The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) describe the `engine` option :

> engine : {‘c’, ‘python’}, optional
>
> Parser engine to use. The C engine is faster while the python engine
>   is currently more feature-complete.

Answer (score 1):

I can't download the linked dataset, but tried to recreate it from your header:

```
In [2]: cat stack53997674.csv
emotion, pixels,  Usage
0,   "70 80 82 72 58 58 60 63 54 58 60 48 89 115 121",   Training
0,   "151 150 147 155 148 133 111 140 170 174 182 15",   Training
2,   "231 212 156 164 174 138 161 173 182 200 106 38",   Training
4,   "24 32 36 30 32 23 19 20 30 41 21 22 32 34 21 1",   Training
6,   "4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 15 23 28 48 50 58 84",   Testing
```

With pandas:

```
In [11]: df = pd.read_csv("stack53997674.csv")
In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
   emotion     ...             Usage
0        0     ...          Training
1        0     ...          Training
2        2     ...          Training
3        4     ...          Training
4        6     ...           Testing

[5 rows x 3 columns]
In [13]: df.dtypes
Out[13]: 
emotion     int64
 pixels    object
  Usage    object
dtype: object
```

`values` is a 2d object dtype array, with strings in the 2nd column:

```
In [20]: df.values[:,1]
Out[20]: 
array(['   "70 80 82 72 58 58 60 63 54 58 60 48 89 115 121"',
       '   "151 150 147 155 148 133 111 140 170 174 182 15"',
       '   "231 212 156 164 174 138 161 173 182 200 106 38"',
       '   "24 32 36 30 32 23 19 20 30 41 21 22 32 34 21 1"',
       '   "4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 15 23 28 48 50 58 84"'],
      dtype=object)
```

With `genfromtxt`:

```
In [21]: data = np.genfromtxt("stack53997674.csv", delimiter=',', names=True, dt
    ...: ype=None, encoding=None, autostrip=True)
In [22]: data
Out[22]: 
array([(0, '"70 80 82 72 58 58 60 63 54 58 60 48 89 115 121"', 'Training'),
       (0, '"151 150 147 155 148 133 111 140 170 174 182 15"', 'Training'),
       (2, '"231 212 156 164 174 138 161 173 182 200 106 38"', 'Training'),
       (4, '"24 32 36 30 32 23 19 20 30 41 21 22 32 34 21 1"', 'Training'),
       (6, '"4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 15 23 28 48 50 58 84"', 'Testing')],
      dtype=[('emotion', '<i8'), ('pixels', '<U48'), ('Usage', '<U8')])
In [23]: data['pixels']
Out[23]: 
array(['"70 80 82 72 58 58 60 63 54 58 60 48 89 115 121"',
       '"151 150 147 155 148 133 111 140 170 174 182 15"',
       '"231 212 156 164 174 138 161 173 182 200 106 38"',
       '"24 32 36 30 32 23 19 20 30 41 21 22 32 34 21 1"',
       '"4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 15 23 28 48 50 58 84"'], dtype='<U48')
```

`pixels` is a 1d array of string dtype.  Both can be converted to/from the other dtype.  And both will require similar processing to produce images.